# Java Mail and Database connections are in conflict

Tags: java, email, jdbc

This is my entire java code. If I comment the line:
`objCon = DriverManager.getConnection(props.getString("url"));` the mail is sending correctly. Else, its throwing the error - `Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.companyname.com, port: 25;`

```
public class PullRec {

private static final Logger LOG_TRACE = Logger.getLogger("debugLogger");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
    Connection objCon = null;  
    PropertyResourceBundle props;
    props = (PropertyResourceBundle) ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.cts.properties.config");
    try {  
        Class.forName(props.getString("dbdriver"));
        // If I comment the below line, the sendmail function works perfectly..!!  
        objCon = DriverManager.getConnection(props.getString("url"));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        LOG_TRACE.info("DBConnection.java FILE ERROR: Disconnected due to "+e);     
    }
    sendmail("Test");

}

public static void sendmail(String strBody) {

      String to = "sarath@companyname.com";

      String from = "sarath@companyname.com";

      String host = "mail.companyname.com";

      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
      properties.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack","true");

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

         message.setSubject("CTS Monitor");

         message.setContent(strBody,"text/html" );  

         Transport.send(message);

         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }
      catch (MessagingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } 
}
}
```

Comment: `<hostname>` is not a valid hostname. Do you mean `localhost`? And do you have a SMTP server running at your machine?

Comment: I would suggest pausing your app with a debugger after creating the jdbc connection and seeing if anything else is using port 25 on your machine with netstat or the like.

Comment: What is your host name?

Comment: Sorry all. Since the hostname is confidential, I cant share.

Comment: Kindly see the updated code to understand more in detail

Answer (score 1):

Your `mail` method is clearly setting the SMTP server hostname to `"<hostname>"`.  That is never going to work.  You need to replace that with the *real* DNS hostname of the SMTP server you are attempting to use.

(Your `from` and `to` addresses are unlikely to work either ...)

---

If you have done that and it still isn't working, then check that you have got the (real) hostname and port correct, and that the SMTP server on that host / port are alive.

---

I notice that you have commented out the call to `mail(String)` which configures the mail server, and I'm not sure what your `Mail` object is, or what the `sendmail` method is actually doing.

(Note: this is NOT all of your Java code, because if it was, it doesn't compile!)

Comment: Kindly see the updated code to understand more in detail